# Where does my toughness bonus as a warrior come from?

Tags: guild-wars-2

As a level 16 Asura warrior, I have 98 in base toughness.

In traits I have +60 defense and +60 healing.

While not wearing any items or signets, and no boons or conditions on my character, I find I have 98+160 toughness.

Where does the last 100 toughness come from?

Comment: Can we get a screenshot to double check everything?

Answer (score 1):

The level 5 defense trait "Thick skin" gives me "Extra armor when health is above 90%".

This is added to my "Toughness" attribute, not my "Defence" secondary attribute as I believed it would, since the description says "Extra armor".

Comment: But you have a stat called 'Armor', don't you, where "thick skin" would apply?

Comment: No. Armor is the collective name of Toughness + Defense.